# Error inmediato al ejecutar stored procedure desde el inicio del Script

Tags: stored-procedure, oracle-11g, packages, toad

estoy intentando ejecutar un Stored Procedure en Toad for Oracle 12.12 pero no he tenido éxito. A penas ejecuto el stored, me salta un error desde la palabra Declare,agradecería su ayuda.

```
DECLARE
   -- Declarations
   var_P_NROTRA    NUMBER;
   var_P_CODUSR    VARCHAR2 (32767);
   var_P_NROTOK    VARCHAR2 (32767);
   var_VR_OUTPUT   SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
   -- Initialization
   var_P_NROTRA := 1;
   var_P_CODUSR := 'CCELIS';
   var_P_NROTOK := '1';

   -- Call
   BSSOFT_APP.APP_PA_001.APP_PR_005 (P_NROTRA    => var_P_NROTRA,
                                     P_CODUSR    => var_P_CODUSR,
                                     P_NROTOK    => var_P_NROTOK,
                                     VR_OUTPUT   => var_VR_OUTPUT);

   -- Transaction Control
   COMMIT;

   -- Output values, do not modify
   :4 := var_VR_OUTPUT;
END;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Agregue la descripción completa del error.

Comment: Revisa [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23999249/4092887) o este [enlace](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_pls_00382_expression_wrong_type.htm). Si no lo ha intentado, busque `pls-00382 expression is of wrong type` en Google.
Si encuentra la respuesta, no olvide publicarla. Saludos.

Comment: la solución me dice que cambie el tipo de dato de NVARCHAR a VARCHAR2 pero mi parámetro ya está definido en VARCHAR2

Answer (score 0):

Es la declaración de la variable `NUMBER` debe ponerle la cantidad de dígitos:

```
DECLARE


-- Declarations
   var_P_NROTRA    NUMBER(5);
   var_P_CODUSR    VARCHAR2 (32767);
   var_P_NROTOK    VARCHAR2 (32767);
   var_VR_OUTPUT   SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
   -- Initialization
   var_P_NROTRA := 1;
   var_P_CODUSR := 'CCELIS';
   var_P_NROTOK := '1';

   -- Call
   BSSOFT_APP.APP_PA_001.APP_PR_005 (P_NROTRA    => var_P_NROTRA,
                                     P_CODUSR    => var_P_CODUSR,
                                     P_NROTOK    => var_P_NROTOK,
                                     VR_OUTPUT   => var_VR_OUTPUT);

   -- Transaction Control
   COMMIT;

   -- Output values, do not modify
   :4 := var_VR_OUTPUT;
END;
```

Comment: le puse la longitud de 5 números,pero nada,aún me sale lo mismo :/